# Stripe - workaround for simulated reader ( emulator) to work in other countries except available ones

Tags: stripe-payments

As per **official docs**:
Stripe Terminal is available in the following countries:

- Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Ireland, the Netherlands, Singapore, the United Kingdom and the United States
- Beta Austria, Belgium, the Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Italy, Luxembourg, Malaysia, New Zealand, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden and Switzerland

Any way I can follow [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/quickstart?integration-country=US&platform=web&reader=wpe) and test the emulated reader outside of these countries?

Looks like VPN doesn't work for this purpose, but may be there is some workaround?

The error code is:

```
{
    "code": "terminal_card_present_unsupported_country",
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Terminal is currently only available in some countries. The card_present source type can not be used in your country in livemode. For more information, see https://stripe.com/docs/terminal.",
    "request_id": "req_19CG2Dma16sqeL",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_19CG2Dma16sqeL?t=1681310345",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
}
```

Tried VPN and setting location manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the simulated reader, this is dependent on the country of your account. You should be able to test this by creating a new test mode Stripe account in the Dashboard and choosing a country where [Terminal is available](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal#learn-about-terminal).